# ASP.NET VB.NET - How to populate Active Directory Logged in Current User's Name into Text Box Field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, windows-authentication, active-directory-group

Background: I have a webForm app that registers a user in the database based on the information provided with a web service, auto-generates a random password and username, and e-mails the user a link to take an application based on the marketing company selected.

Question:

- How do I populate the MarketerName_TextBox field with the currently logged in users name (Is it User.Identity.Name and do I add that line on aspx.vb end or the aspx end?)

Here's a screenshot of the front end:
[image: web app screenshot]

I've been going off the code from [Wrox's Windows Authentication Tutorial](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-3-5-Windows-Based-Authentication.id-310905.html) but it's not thorough enough for what I'm trying to do.

web.config file:

web.config file (pertinent code displayed only):

```
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
   <authorization>

    <allow users="alg\bmccarthy, alg\phoward" />               
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_Admin" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_AMG" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_BIG" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_NIS" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_GLA" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PIP" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PSM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_PAM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_ANN" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_AAM" />
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_MWM" /> 
    <allow roles="alg\ACOMP_user_GIM" />
    <deny users="*" />        
</authorization> 

   <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
  <endpoint address="http://172.17.1.40/aCompService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService" contract="aComp_ServiceReference.IAcompService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcompService" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

default.aspx.vb code w/ the txtMarketerName_TextChanged() and Page_Load() Methods:

```
Private Sub GetCarriers()
    Dim ac1 As Array
    ac1 = proxy.GetCarrierNames("test", "test")
    For Each item In ac1
        lbCarriers.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}", item.CarrierID, item.CarrierNameLong, item.CarrierNameShort))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub txtMarketerName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMarketerName.TextChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load, Me.Load, Me.Load

    If Not lbCarriers.Items.Count > 0 Then
        GetCarriers()
        GetMarketingCompanies()
    End If

End Sub
```

default.aspx code where the text box field for the Marketer name is displayed:

```
<table id="Table1" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" align=center>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">
            My Name (auto-populated Current Logged In User's Name): </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarketerName" runat="server" Width="250px">    
        </asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style2">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="regValMarketerName" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="txtMarketerName" ErrorMessage="Marketer Name is required" Text="*"
ValidationGroup="Valtxt">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks for looking!

If you have any helpful links or suggestions, I'll give you an up-vote!

Comment: you mention in the title and the question using windows authentication, but your web.config is using FormsAuthentication providers. Is this site intended for an intranet? can you show the entire web.config?

Comment: @Zach, thanks for your response! I just added the rest of the web.config on there. I wrote this project using a ASP.NET w VB.NET VS2010 Template so I might have to make some extra changes to the webconfig to make the win authentiction work. What should I change?

Comment: So your intention is for the site to be an INTRANET site that is accessed by users who have a Windows account in your domain?

Comment: so why do the users need to register accounts with usernames and passwords if you already have access to their windows domain accounts?

Comment: should i delete all the providers info so that it is <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"/> and make roleManager so that it is: <roleManager enabled="true"
             defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/> ?

Comment: I think you need to take a larger look at what you are doing. Should users be registering accounts if you are using Windows authentication? Here is the MSDN article for implementing Windows authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx

Comment: @Zach, I've been to that site and it only has 4 lines of code and not the complete example web.config. do you know of any links to a conplete web.config that I can use as a template?

Comment: That is all the code you need to get Windows authentication working. Here is an example with more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: @Zach, ok i got the authentication to work. How do I populate the MarketerName_TextBox field with the currently logged in users name (Is it User.Identity.Name and do I add that line on aspx.vb end or the aspx end?)
How do I get only the currently logged in user's groups to show up under the MarketingCo_DropDownList (For Example: if the current user is in the ACOMP_user_PSM group, only load PSM in dropdown list)

Comment: these are each new questions. you need to post them as new questions. how to populate a textbox with the current user's windows username and how to retrieve a user's groups and populate a ddl list with that list.

Comment: Those were my initial questions.... but you got hung up on some things in the web.config which didn't make sense but wasn't effecting my active directory access to the website.... well, will u plz post something as an answer so i can close out this question and add a separate question for - How do I get only the currently logged in user's groups to show up under the MarketingCo_DropDownList (For Example: if the current user is in the ACOMP_user_PSM group, only load PSM in dropdown list)

Comment: True, I did get hung up the fact that you were trying to create accounts for Windows users when they already have an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of a label or textbox to the current windows user's username in the code behind in the Page_Load evemt like so:

```
txtUsername.Text = User.Identity.Name;
```

Or you can do it in the mark up like so:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUsername"><%=User.Identity.Name %></asp:Label>
```

Comment: thanks for your response! If you have chance, Please check out my other active directory membership related question out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731040/

Comment: I see windowsIdentity.Name being used sometimes. Whats the difference between that and User.Identity.Name?

Comment: What's the difference between WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name and User.Identity.Name?

Comment: http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount

Comment: given my application requirements, i have anonymous users disabled. Should I have Impersonation disabled too?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using under the deafult.aspx.vb code-behind page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load, Me.Load, Me.Load

    If Not lbCarriers.Items.Count > 0 Then
        txtMarketerName.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name
        GetCarriers()
        GetMarketingCompanies()
    End If

End Sub
```

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name Versus User.Identity.Name

The WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() method returns a WindowsIdentity instance that represents the identity running the thread. The User.Identity object represents the identity that was passed from IIS. If IIS allows a user to access a page anonymously, the User.Identity.Name property will return an empty string. Otherwise, it will return the account name of the user authenticated by IIS.

User.Identity.Name - Returns : my_domain\jdoe

System.Environment.UserName Returns: jdoe